# Moving label code from playgrounds to storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uilabel

I am starting to explore Swift2 with no previous programming experience.

I have the folowing code which works great in Playgrounds, using quick view and the in-line view methods.

How do I relate it to an actual label in my storyboard?

```
import UIKit

let myLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50))
myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()  
myLabel.text = "Hello Swift"  
myLabel.textAlignment = .Center   
myLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 24)
```

*Excerpt From: Smyth, Neil. “iOS 9 App Development Essentials.” Payload Media, 0101-01-01T00:00:00+00:00. iBooks. 
This material may be protected by copyright.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your code inside of the `viewDidLoad()` method within your viewController. Next, you would want to add your label to your main view.

An example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50))
    myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    myLabel.text = "Hello Swift"
    myLabel.textAlignment = .Center
    myLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 24)
    self.view.addSubview(myLabel)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add the label to your view:
Go to your ViewController.swift file, and add the following code:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    //Add the code for your label here
    self.view.addSubview(myLabel)
}
```